# Newsletter link to anchor

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, anchor, newsletter

How to make a link to a line of the same page in a HTML e-mail? 
I tried `<a href="#1"> link to name </a>` and after testing it on Gmail and Outlook, the `#1` is transformed to  `#**********_1` and nothing happens when I click the link. I'm using 1&1 Newsletter system to send the HTML email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your 1&1 newsletter software is adding tracking to your link. If there is an option to turn this off, your anchor link should work correctly.

Here is a [support chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/) for anchor links in html email

Comment: I set the anchor using `<a name="1"></a>` then I call it by `href="#1"` and everything goes fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It is the way Gmail and Outlook are setup. Their code overrides your link and since they want users to keep their mail page open, it opens all links in new tabs. Even with plain links such as http://google.com they will open in new tabs.

Comment: I just saw a newsletter with page jumps links and it's working perfectly. Check my edit please.

Comment: I should set the anchor by `<a name="1"></a>` then call it by `href="#1"`.